# MS Access average a value based on other column data

Tags: sql, ms-access, average

So my data looks something like this:

```
Smpl_id Plate_id CT_Value
  1        1       27
  1        1       32
  2        1       56
  2        1       49
  1        2       40
  1        2       36
  2        2       58
  2        2       64
```

I would like to design a query that returns averages of `CT_Value` of each sample in a plate, so it would look like this:

```
Smpl_id Plate_id Avg_CT
  1         1     29.5
  2         1     52.5
  1         2     38
  2         2     61
```

I have tried

```
Avg_CT: DAvg("[CT_Value]","[qPCR_sample_data]","[Plate_id] = '" & [Plate_id] & "'" And "[Smpl_is] = '" & [Smpl_id] & "'")
```

But that just results in:

```
Smpl_id Plate_id CT_Value
  1        1      45.25
  1        1      45.25
  2        1      45.25
  2        1      45.25
  1        2      45.25
  1        2      45.25
  2        2      45.25
  2        2      45.25
```

I can't just list the plate or sample id numbers because this is actually a long list that is continually growing. I also need to use these average numbers in future calculations (that I have already figured out how to do).

Also, I have just started using MS Access (designing a brand new database), so I kinda understand SQL but have very little actual experience in it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a group by query.

- Create a new query, and add the table (in my example I've called it tblSample).
- Add the three fields, Smpl_id, Plate_id and CT_Value to the query grid.
- On the Query Design memubar, click on the button labelled "Totals".
- This introduces a new row in the query grid called "Total", with all three fields having it set to "Group By".
- Simply change the "Group By" for CT_Value to "Avg", and run the query to get the results you are after:

[image]

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use simple aggregation such as:

```
select t.smpl_id, t.plate_id, avg(t.ct_value) as avg_ct
from qpcr_sample_data t
group by t.smpl_id, t.plate_id
```